# PHP preg_replace insert a string where there is none

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable $var which contains a string.

Example:

```
$var = "one, two , three = ?, four = 'val', five  , six = 1, seven, eight = 'val' , nine";
```

I want to edit $var with preg_replace() in such a way that $var will look like this:

```
"one = ?, two = ?, three = ?, four = 'val', five = ?, six = 1, seven = ?, eight = 'val', nine = ?"
```

I mean: If the column doesn't have an assigned value, set to it a `' = ?'` and remove unnecessary spaces.

I tried the following regex, but it's not even close:

```
$sql['set'] = preg_replace("/(\w+)\s?,/", "$1 = ?,", $sql['set']);
```

I researched for solutions but I can't cover all posibilities.

Comment: Why is it not even close? https://regex101.com/r/gDIrMS/1

Comment: If the question is about regexp, thats an example how to do it: 
https://regex101.com/r/pM4bV7/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will take care of your missing `= ?` in your initial string,

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:(,)|$)
```

When replaced by `\1 = ?\2` but for trimming extra spaces before comma you will need another regex `+,` to be replaced by `,` hence you can use this multi replace in php with this code,

```
$var = "one, two , three = ?, four = 'val', five  , six = 1, seven, eight = 'val' , nine";
echo preg_replace(['/([a-zA-Z]+)\s*(?:(,)|$)/i', '/ +,/i'], ['\1 = ?\2', ','], $var);
```

Which gives your desired output,

```
one = ?, two = ?, three = ?, four = 'val', five = ?, six = 1, seven = ?, eight = 'val', nine = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

It's almost there indeed.

- You just need `*` as quantifier for the space instead of `?`.
- Ideally not use `\w` to match the keys, because that would accidentally match `= 1` as well.
- Perhaps use some [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for ensuring there's no `=` before.

I'd go for something like:

```
preg_replace("/ (?<= ^|,|,\s)  ([a-z]+)  (?=\s*(,|$)) /x", "$1 = ?", $var)
#                       ↑         ↑            ↑
#              preceding comma   key   following comma / end
```

The preceding comma match is a bit hackish (just looks for a single optional space), but also redundant if you constrain the allowed key names.

Answer (score 1):

here's a non regex solution:

```
$var = "one, two , three = ?, four = 'val', five  , six = 1, seven, eight = 'val' , nine";
$arr = explode(',', $var);
foreach($arr as $i => $e)
{
    $arr[$i] = (strpos($e, '=') === false) ? trim($e).' = ?' : trim($e);
}

echo implode(', ', $arr);
```

Comment: @Dharman - I wrote it quickly just to give him an idea. here's a shorter version. There's always a better shorter version.

Comment: You can still reduce `trim` to call only once. `array_map` might even be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) check if the value does not match a key = value pattern. Then if it does not, add `= ?` to the value.

Pattern

```
\w+\h*=\h*\S
```

That will match

- `\w+\h*` match 1+ word characters followed by 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `=` Match literally
- `\h*\S` Match 0+ horizontal whitespaces followed by matching not a whitespace character

For example

```
$var = "one, two , three = ?, four = 'val', five  , six = 1, seven, eight = 'val' , nine";

echo implode(', ', array_map(function($x){
    return preg_match('/\w+\h*=\h*\S/', $x) === 0 ? $x.' = ?' : $x;
}, array_map("trim", explode(',', $var))));
```

Result

```
one = ?, two = ?, three = ?, four = 'val', five = ?, six = 1, seven = ?, eight = 'val', nine = ?
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ZYGAC)

Without using a regex and the column name itself can not contain an equals sign, you might use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if the string contains a `=`:

```
$var = "one, two , three = ?, four = 'val', five  , six = 1, seven, eight = 'val' , nine";

echo implode(', ', array_map(function($x){
    return strpos($x, '=') === false ? $x.' = ?' : $x;
}, array_map("trim", explode(',', $var))));
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SXKK4)

Comment: As a fringe consideration, these explosions might not be reliable if one of the quoted values contains a comma.